# Getting 2 outputs for the same code

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe, fork

I am using linux\unix os. When I ran below code I am getting 2 outputs. Mentioned below:

a)  12345-
b)  1-2-3-4-5-

Can anyone let me know why and how the above 2 outputs are coming?

```
int main() 
{
 int i, n, pfds[2];
 char c, buf[80];

 pipe(pfds);
 if (fork() == 0) 
 {
   for (c='1'; c<='5'; c++) 
     write(pfds[1], &c, 1);
 } 
 else 
 {
   close(pfds[1]);
   while ((n = read(pfds[0], buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) 
   {
    write(1, buf, n);
    write(1, "-", 1);
   }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux buffers your write into the pipe and at some point it flushes the buffer and the read fork reads everything in one go. You should be able to change this by doing a fflush() after the write.

Comment: fflush only affect the stdio buffer (fwrite and others), which he not use.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using array of character to print only single char? Don't use stdio buffer to print character.

i have modified you declaration form char buf[80] to buf.

```
while ((n = read(pfds[0], &buf, 1)) > 0)
{
 write(1, &buf, n);
 write(1, "-", 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A pipe is a stream. It means that you will get on one end all the characters sent from the other and in same order. But the *packets* are not preserved. Race conditions allow one read to get everything or only one char at a time, or everythin in between...

If you want to process on char at a time (and get `1-2-3-4-5-`)

```
while ((n = read(pfds[0], buf, 1)) > 0) 
{
 write(1, buf, n);
 write(1, "-", 1);
}
```

If you prefere to process everything on a whole (and get `12345-`):

```
int tot = 0
while ((n = read(pfds[0], buf+tot, sizeof(buf)-tot)) > 0) tot += n; /* gather everything */
write(1, buf, tot);
write(1, "-", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call read(), the function will read so many chars as available till there are no more left or hit count.

When you run it with sizeof(buf), you may read 1,2..5 chars, if there was allready 5 chars in the pipe as in your a run, you read all chars, output a "-" and the next read return 0, because the pipe is empty and no one write to it anymore.

If there is only 1 char in the pipe, as in your b run, then you read only one char, output "-" and then read and wait till the child write more to the buffer. That there are only one is because you child was scheduled after write one char.